# There is no visual screen on my Android Development Virtual Device?

Tags: android, screen, emulation, adt

After looking up some answers I didn't find anyone with the same problem as I did.

I know that the emulators can sometimes take time, but after leaving it run for about 10 minutes I think I waited long enough. It is not that I don't see anything, the "Android" starting screen showed up and then it went to the homescreen where I could adjust the volume and see the time on the phone but that was it. The only dynamic buttons that I could press with "dynamic hardware controls" was the volume, and the power on and off buttons. I didn't get the normal homescreen like seen in the tutorials.

[image: These are my settings. Maybe this is the problem?]

[image: This what I see when I wait a while and starting the emulator. The time is there just no homescreen or anything.]

Comment: please select another CPU/ABI insted Android Wear...

Comment: your monitor is not supporting the Xhdpi density.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select this ARM (armeabi-v7a) value instead Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a) for CPU/ABI option at device creation time because Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a) Wear development test not for normal Application development.

Comment: Hey, sorry but this didn't help anything I got the same results. Any other suggestions?